# Regular Expression: Matches some characters or no character

Tags: regex

I expected a string to be either "abc", "adc" or "ac". How to say that in regular expression?

Comment: What seems to be a problem?

Comment: Use the `|` operator to specify alternatives: http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html

Comment: You need to add some code , showing us what you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `|` (OR) operator like so:

```
abc|adc|ac
```

It is equivalent to saying *Select abc or adc or ac*

You can use tools like [RegExr](http://regexr.com) or [Regex101](http://regex101.com) to test your RegEx

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/qZ5aT3/1)</kbd>

---

There is also a clever to do it, that is shorter. Since all 3 strings start with an `a`, the first part of the RegEx will be `a`. They all end in a `c`, so the last part will be a `c`.

Now the middle letter is either a `b` or `d`. You could use `(b|d)`, or you can use the shorter `[bd]` (it means the same thing). You can use the `?` to state that the middle letter is optional.

So your full RegEx will be:

```
a[bd]?c
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/yB4mG8/1)</kbd>

Comment: a[bd]?c is the helpful answer. I actually doesn't know what "a" and "c" will be, but I know what will separate them. And Live Demo is also bonus point. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the simple way:

```
abc|adc|ac
```

or the more 'advanced' way:

```
a[bd]?c
```

Both should Work.